# Replace character in string in an .each statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use this to clean up my select options as they come in from AJAX. Many of them have an "_" in them and I want to remove them:

```
$.each(data, function(i, data) {
    $('#first_select2').append("<option>" + data.COLUMN_NAME + "</option>");               
    $('#first_select2').replace(/_/g, " ");
});
```

The replace works fine if I try to use it outside of an each. If I use it in the .each, I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Is there a way to do what I need here?

Comment: replace `_` in `data.COLUMN_NAME`? if so, do it before you append.

Comment: `$('#first_select2')` <-- This is a jQuery object but 


`.replace(/_/g, " ")`  <-- "replace" works on strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to replace `_` in `data.COLUMN_NAME`, do it before you append, like below.

```
$.each(data, function(i, data) {
    $('#first_select2').append("<option>" + (data.COLUMN_NAME.replace(/_/g, " ")) + "</option>");
});
```

As later, you were trying to replace `_` in a select box instead of options's  text.

Answer (score 0):

Should you using spesific datatype ajax, like as datatype:'json', so you will get return clean result..

If you had using json, you can replace in your php (str.replace) code and then pass to echo json_encode(your result), and than place that on your select option.